# How to get the value and size of dynamic table's columns and rows

Tags: karate

I have used Karate for API testing and succeeded with one project. And now I am exploring the Karate UI for an another project and I am stuck with getting values from the dynamic table's column and rows and also I want to check its size.

I have gone through the documentation and found some way to handle it like using locateAll and scriptAll but it didn't help.

My table looks like below

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>column1</th>
   <th>column2</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>row1</tr>
  <tr>row2</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I have achieved this in selenium by the below code

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"PartialRateTableListModel\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/thead/tr")
    private static WebElement columns;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"PartialRateTableListModel\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody")
    private static WebElement rows;

List<WebElement> TotalColsList = columns.findElements(By.tagName("th"));
Assert.assertEquals(2, TotalColsList.size());

    List<WebElement>TotalRowsList = rows.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    Assert.assertEquals(2, TotalRowsList.size());
```

I want to this in our Karate UI. Can you please help me to overcome this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def cols = scriptAll('th', "_.innerHTML")
* match cols == ['column1', 'column2']
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks. It works fine. But I want to filter the <tr> in <tbody> tag. How can I do this and also how can I short this scriptAll function to find a particular table if a page has more than one tables. If this can be also achieved I am good to go for implementation. Can you please help to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RajkamalS ask a new question if needed, you can use any valid XPath or CSS selector in place of the `th`, try it and see