# fetch specific value from list of webelement using karate

Tags: karate

i have one webpage, using CSS selector it return list of webelement. I want to fetch specific index value from it using karate DSL. can anyone please help.

Comment: see this link. else your question is really incomplete: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65844733/143475 also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61236245/143475